# How can i color each wall in another color?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectsGrid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gridBlock;

    public int worldWidth = 10;
    public int worldHeight = 10;

    public List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();

    private List<GameObject> GameObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    void Start()
    {
        GenerateGrid();

        GetPositions();
    }

    private void GenerateGrid()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < worldWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < worldHeight; z++)
            {
                GameObject block = Instantiate(gridBlock, Vector3.zero, gridBlock.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                block.transform.parent = transform;
                block.transform.name = "Block";
                block.transform.tag = "Block";
                block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x, 0, z);

                GameObjects.Add(block);
            }
        }
    }

    private void GetPositions()
    {
        // Top wall

        for (int i = 0; i < worldWidth; i++)
        {
            positions.Add(new Vector3(0,0, i));
        }

        // Left wall

        for (int i = 0; i < worldHeight; i++)
        {
            positions.Add(new Vector3(i,0, 0));
        }

        // Right wall

        for (int i = 0; i < worldHeight; i++)
        {
            positions.Add(new Vector3(i,0, worldWidth -1));
        }

        // Bottom wall

        for (int i = 0; i < worldWidth; i++)
        {
            positions.Add(new Vector3(worldHeight -1,0, i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < GameObjects.Count; x++)
            {
                if (GameObjects[x].transform.localPosition == positions[i])
                {
                    GameObjects[x].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to color each wall in another color.
For example the Top wall in red.

Now it will color all the positions objects in red.
But i want somehow to find in the loop when it's getting to the next wall positions and color it in another color.

Maybe i need to use dictionaries somehow ?

Comment: Have you considered integrating that color assignment into `GenerateGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the x and z are known in each case, simply check the value.

```
private void GetPositions()
    {
        // Top wall

        for (int i = 0; i < worldWidth; i++)
        {
            positions.Add(new Vector3(0,0, i));
        }

        // Left wall

        for (int i = 0; i < worldHeight; i++)
        {
            positions.Add(new Vector3(i,0, 0));
        }

        // Right wall

        for (int i = 0; i < worldHeight; i++)
        {
            positions.Add(new Vector3(i,0, worldWidth -1));
        }

        // Bottom wall

        for (int i = 0; i < worldWidth; i++)
        {
            positions.Add(new Vector3(worldHeight -1,0, i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < GameObjects.Count; x++)
            {
                if (GameObjects[x].transform.localPosition == positions[i])
                {
                     if(GameObjects[x].transform.localPosition.x==0)//TOP
                        GameObjects[x].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                     else if(GameObjects[x].transform.localPosition.z == 0)//LEFT
                        GameObjects[x].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
                     else if(GameObjects[x].transform.localPosition.z == worldWidth -1)//RIGHT
                        GameObjects[x].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
                     else if(GameObjects[x].transform.localPosition.x == worldHeight -1)//BOTTOM
                        GameObjects[x].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Helpful Hint: It should be noted that there are better ways to look up game objects from the scene that prevent you from accidentally selecting an object that just happens to have the transform you're looking for. It also saves you the trouble of iterating over every object in the game. Do some reading on the FindGameObject methods.